# Default to a value when a sub-query statement fails?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have the following query:

```
    INSERT  INTO dbo.ResourceOrderCustomersOrders
            ( OrderId ,
              Type ,
              CustomerId ,
              ResourceId ,
              Quantity ,
              Created ,
              CreatedBy             
            )
    VALUES  ( ( SELECT  MAX(OrderId) + 1
                FROM    dbo.ResourceOrderCustomersOrders
              ) , -- OrderId - int
              'PENDING' , -- Type - varchar(50)
              ( SELECT  MAX(CustomerId)
                FROM    dbo.ResourceOrderCustomers
                WHERE   UPPER(FirstName) = UPPER(@Firstname)
                        AND UPPER(Surname) = UPPER(@Surname)
                        AND UPPER(Email) = UPPER(@Email)
              ) , -- CustomerId - int
              ( SELECT  MAX(ResourceId)
                FROM    dbo.ResourceOrderFormContent
                WHERE   DisplayTitle = @ResourceName
              ) , -- ResourceId - int
              @ResourceQuantity ,
              GETDATE() , -- Created - datetime
              'WebsiteForm' -- CreatedBy - varchar(20)

            );
```

In cases where a subquery fails I'd like to default to a value of my choosing (to hold unspecified records).

For example, were the following to fail to retrieve a result because a record doesn't exist:

```
SELECT  MAX(ResourceId)
FROM    dbo.ResourceOrderFormContent
WHERE   DisplayTitle = @ResourceName
```

Then I would want to return the number '999' (unspecified record). What would be the best way to approach this?

I've tried to use try / catch but I'm being told this is invalid syntax. Here is my attempt:

```
    INSERT  INTO dbo.ResourceOrderCustomersOrders
            ( OrderId ,
              Type ,
              CustomerId ,
              ResourceId ,
              Quantity ,
              Created ,
              CreatedBy             
            )
    VALUES  ( ( SELECT  MAX(OrderId) + 1
                FROM    dbo.ResourceOrderCustomersOrders
              ) , -- OrderId - int
              'PENDING' , -- Type - varchar(50)
              ( SELECT  MAX(CustomerId)
                FROM    dbo.ResourceOrderCustomers
                WHERE   UPPER(FirstName) = UPPER(@Firstname)
                        AND UPPER(Surname) = UPPER(@Surname)
                        AND UPPER(Email) = UPPER(@Email)
              ) , -- CustomerId - int
              ( BEGIN TRY
                    SELECT  MAX(ResourceId)
                    FROM    dbo.ResourceOrderFormContent
                    WHERE   DisplayTitle = @ResourceName
                END TRY
                BEGIN CATCH
                    SELECT 999
                END CATCH
              ) , -- ResourceId - int
              @ResourceQuantity ,
              GETDATE() , -- Created - datetime
              'WebsiteForm' -- CreatedBy - varchar(20)

            );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Max` will always return `NULL` if no rows found. So You can use `ISNULL`.

```
SELECT  ISNULL(MAX(ResourceId), 999)
FROM    dbo.ResourceOrderFormContent
WHERE   DisplayTitle = @ResourceName
```